# Make Jquery Accordion script to allow multiple accordions on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm using the following accordion script: http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/accordion.html

However I noticed that when I put multiple accordions/containers on one page, when I close an element in one accordion, it closes all elements in all accordions. I need it to where the accordions act independently of each other.

In the script's github, it does look like someone tried to fix this issue: https://github.com/juven14/Accordion/pull/4/files However when I implemented that fix, it killed the accordions completely.

If anyone can figure out how to adjust that script to where each accordion acts on its own, that would be amazing!

Comment: I think you are using multiple **id**s in a single **html** file. Can you provide the code of your **html** file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix https://github.com/juven14/Accordion/pull/4/files seems to have a typo on line 129, `opt` should be `opts`:

Try to change:

```
opened = $this.parent().find('.' + opt.cssOpen);
```

To:

```
opened = $this.parent().find('.' + opts.cssOpen);
```